# Problem with including JS files on a HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, tooltip

I am trying to use a tooltip jQuery plugin. This is what I have in `<head>` of `index.html`:

```
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/simpletip-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/homepage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

And this is in `js/homepage.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // meaningless functions

    $('.supported_hosts').simpletip({
        fixed: true,
        position: 'right',
        content: 'test content.'
    });
});
```

But for some reason, the tooltip doesn't show. But it does show if I include the tooltip function on the index page. Is there any way to get this working without having the tooltip function on the index page, but in an external file? Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if you have an error in your js file somewhere else? Can you post the whole file or double check that you don't have errors somewhere else?

Comment: Try adding `defer="defer"` to your js/homepage.js script tag.

Comment: Already have, you can safely assume there are no errors anywhere else. I checked it with Console2 and Firebug too.

Comment: Are you seeing any JavaScript errors when your code is in an external file?

Comment: Works perfect with Robusto's fix. Never seen that before actually, i'll have to Google it. Thanks. :)

Comment: Strange, as JavaScript files are loaded sequentially so both `$(document).ready` and `simpletip` have to be available when loading `js/homepage.js`. Do you have an example page, so we can test this ourselves?

Comment: Good practice would be for Robusto to provide the comment as an answer and for Prupper to accept it. That way this question wouldn't remain 'unanswered'.

Answer (score 1):

I have never use the simplest plug in but i copy and pasted your header and your js code and everything seemed to work just fine.

I linked to the latest version of jquery and downloaded a fresh copy of simpletip.js and it worked with on the first try.

The only differences are/maybe:
 - I don't know what your code looks like where you call 'supported_hosts' class in the html. 
 - The name of the simpletip.js file I didn't change it upon download, so I would check your file names and relative location.

Sorry there wasn't something more but what you have worked for me, here is the code I used in full incase this helps you:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.simpletip-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="homepage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
     <span class="supported_hosts">Tool Tips here</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript you gave:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // meaningless functions

    $('.supported_hosts').simpletip({
        fixed: true,
        position: 'right',
        content: 'test content.'
    });
});
```

I downloaded the simpletip.js here:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-simpletip/downloads/detail?name=jquery.simpletip-1.3.1.min.js&can=2&q=

I would just double check your relative paths and class naming. Your code looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Moving

```
<script src="homepage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to the end of the body seemed to solve the problem:

```
<body>

[code...]

<script src="homepage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```